# Fusion table suppressInfoWindows not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a problem with suppressInfoWindows its not seems to work on my map when declared in map option. Any ideas

```
 function updateLayerQuery(layer, sector, county) {
        var where = "Sector = '" + sector + "'";
        if (county) {
          where += " AND County = '" + county + "'";
        }
        layer.setOptions({
          query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1xeq1_MLccx-A2spFLz_nc35xQwsBZNhwgGnUn1wY',
            where: where,
            suppressInfoWindows: true
          }
```

full code on CodePen http://codepen.io/PiotrKrosniak/pen/VaEbBa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`suppressInfoWindows` is a property of the [FusionTableLayersOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions) object, not the [FusionTablesQuery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesQuery) object.

```
function updateLayerQuery(layer, sector, county) {
    var where = "Sector = '" + sector + "'";
    if (county) {
      where += " AND County = '" + county + "'";
    }
    layer.setOptions({
      suppressInfoWindows: true, // should be here
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1xeq1_MLccx-A2spFLz_nc35xQwsBZNhwgGnUn1wY',
        where: where,
      }
```